# jQuery/AJAX image upload plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, image-uploading

My client needs to be able to upload images to their site to keep it updated, so I'm hoping there is a jQuery plugin that will do the following->

- Upload an image file
- Verify that the file is in the required dimension to fit on the site (if the user could re-size right on the page that would be great, but not essential)
- Rename the file and place it in the database for later referencing

***Also to note- I would like to be able to use the plugin multiple times on a page and have it accept different values for different photo categories. Again this is preferable but not essential

Thank you!

Comment: I realize that the server side needs to happen in PHP, but if the plugin had a way to link to that... I dunno, this is mostly just wishful thinking, curious to see what type of stuff is out there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 3):

Or take a look at this script: [jQuery image upload and crop](http://www.ephespage.de/artikel/detail/a/n/si/ch/t/jquery-image-upload-and-crop-script-with-preview-and-resizing.html)

It's using the asido project based on PHP and the imgAreaSelect plugin for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very old, and I believe it's no longer relevant, but other readers might be interested. I recently wrote a jquery plugin that does exactly what you ask, and even more:

https://github.com/andyvr/picEdit